# Python 2.7, restart loop

Tags: python-2.7, loops, count

i am trying to loop though a series of numbers and assign a constant index to them with restarting a loop at a certain number.
input numbers
0
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
0
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
......
the expected output should be 
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2

my code looks like this. I works but never stops.
How could i iterate over the input data?

```
count = 1
for line in in_file:
    should_restart = True
    while should_restart:
      should_restart = False
      for i in xrange(0,22,3):
        print count
        if i == 21:
           should_restart = True
           count+=1
           break
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your current code doesn't do anything with `line`, and just prints seven copies of each number in a row forever. But I'm not sure I understand how that's different than what you want. Can you clarify what the relationship between input and output should be?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have an `in_file` like this (that's just an example yours is different but I wanted to do it with your given input):

```
in_file = "0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21"
in_file = in_file.split(" ")
```

you setup an end-condition for your counter and a starting count:

```
end_condition = 21
count = 1
```

then you iterate through your list:

```
for line in in_file:
    line = int(line) # This is only needed if you have string-data
```

within the loop print the current count:

```
    print(count, end=' ')
```

and later increment the counter if you reach the final value:

```
    if line == end_condition:
        count += 1
```